# Notification icon is not changed with .setSmallIcon

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am implementing Notifications in `android`. I want to change the icon of notification, but the problem is that `setSmallIcon` is not working. My custom icon is showing in the `lollipop` device but not showing the custom icon above `lollipop` devices.

I have tried the following code:

```
send_notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.book2);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setContentTitle("New Book Added")
                        .setContentText("Android with java")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                                    .bigPicture(icon)
                                    .bigLargeIcon(null));
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
                } else {
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
                }
                NotificationManager manager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                manager.notify(1,builder.build());
            }
}
```

The big picture is also not showing. Please Help.

EDIT:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String text = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        builder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigLargeIcon(icon));

    } else if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String text = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        builder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigLargeIcon(icon));

    }

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Testing channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

    }
    manager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling the 100% fresh App. Android keeps cache so things work more quickly and the notification is one of those things.

Uninstalling and reinstalling worked for my issue some time ago.

Also do remember that in Android Oreo and above, in order for notifications to work; notification channels must be created and also the notification that you're creating should be assigned to one of them.

#### EDIT

What I've tried (and it works for me): (Sample in Kotlin but should be similar enough);

```
fun onClick(view: View) {
    var icon_resource = R.drawable.ic_mtrl_chip_close_circle
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        icon_resource = R.drawable.ic_mtrl_chip_checked_circle
    }

    val icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)

    val notification =  NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(icon_resource)
        .setContentTitle("New Book Added")
        .setContentText("Android with java")
        .setLargeIcon(icon)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(icon)
            .bigLargeIcon(null)).build()

   val manager=  getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
   manager.notify(1,notification)
}
```

### SECOND EDIT

I think there's a problem with your image, (as there was in mine; sizes or something). After spending a lot of time trying to figure out why it didn't display the launcher icon in the notifications I decided to try with one of my images that I had laying around...

#### Tested with Android O; API 28

### And here are the results:

[image: Collapsed]
[image: Expanded]

Feel free to try with the original image I used:
[image: WTF_Gopher]

### Here's the code that is powering these results; it's not very different from the first one...

```
// Parametherise this drawable with an if statement of your own
var icon_resource = R.drawable.ic_mtrl_chip_close_circle

val manager=  NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
// This is required because the testing device is an Android O
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    manager.createNotificationChannel(
        NotificationChannel("CUSTOM_NOTIFICATIONS", "StackOverflow", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    )
}

val icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.mipmap.dafuq)

val notification =  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CUSTOM_NOTIFICATIONS")
    .setSmallIcon(icon_resource)
    .setContentTitle("New Book Added")
    .setContentText("Android with java")
    .setLargeIcon(icon)
    .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
        .bigPicture(icon)
        .bigLargeIcon(null)).build()

manager.notify(1,notification)
```

#### Additional info:

When I'm using a wrong image, I get this pesky log in my Logcat. Check for the same or similars!
`2019-04-10 20:11:02.120 3434-3434/com.example.deletemeapp D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'`

Comment: What icon isnt exactly shown? The app icon or the picture inside the notification?

Comment: it is showing default launcher icon. i want my custom icon which i have made with image assets. and also big picture icon is not showing

Comment: But the notification does pop up?

Comment: In which android version are you currently trying to display the notification?

Comment: i am trying on marshmallow.my custom icon is showing in lollipop devices, but not above than that

Comment: Should you check for `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP` instead of `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP`?

Comment: Emphasizing > and >= (Including Lollipop and above)? Or did you mean to check for `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP`

Comment: Also, when fiddling with notifications I suggest you **FULLY** uninstall the App in each retry since Android caches most things and you end up wasting time doing things that actually didn't have any sideffects on your machine.

Comment: And you're sure the conditions aren't mislead?

Comment: Make sure that the "special" icon is not transparent/white

Comment: the condition is to check if the version is greater than lollipop than show transparent icon.because in above lollipop versions,transparent icon is required

Comment: So use strict > instead of >=?

Comment: Hmm... Try using `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)` in order to get the notification manager instead of trying to get the system's service

Comment: Like so; if we're inside an activity:

`NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MyActivity.this);`
`manager.notify(1, notification);`

Comment: i have tried your image,but still bigpicture is not showing in my marshmallow device.and when i tested in lollipop device,white blank image is showing instead of the actuall image :( i dnt know what to do now

Comment: I mean, the snippet works for me in every device I have tested so far... 
Share your final code you're trying this with, please

Comment: OK; Channel creation must be BEFORE creating a notification. Please change the mipmap to a bigger image than the ic_launcher; like the one I provided (also try that it is a .png file). (For the `setSmallIcon` any image is OK)

In the bigStyle-->  `bigPicture(icon)` and `bigLargeIcon(null)` [so you don't display the thumbnail of the image when the notification is expanded].

Get the notification manager from `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);`

Once that is done, clean the project's build cache, fully uninstall the app, and then launch it from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create the notification icon as follows:

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setContentTitle("New Book Added")
                .setContentText("Android with java");
```

Now Add:

```
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle s = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap_image);
        s.setSummaryText("Summary text appears on expanding the notification");
        //Set the style of the notification to this big picture style
        builder.setStyle(s);
```

For the versioning add this:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
       // Marshmallow+
   }else{
        //below Marshmallow
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Are you sure about that? According to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications, it seems that setSmallIcon and setLargeIcon work perfectly fine for Android O

Comment: And if you need a tutorial on creating notifications go here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-notifications/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#2

Comment: As I have tried both in my real phone and the emulator; the default icon given by the project doesn't work. The resolution is not high enough and hence the OpenGLRenderer logcat error log. Is not a problem in decoding a bitmap, but the resulting bitmap itself.

Also it's not that it "doesn't work"; but the bitmap is not properly displayed

Comment: Also the Logcat states: "unimplemented" which sounds **really** suspicious

Comment: @Aaron yes we can use setLargeIcon for changing the default icon.But now problem is that, bigpicture is not showing in any device.

Comment: @UserAbdur is there a reason you are setting the bigLargeIcon() to null? That might also interfering in the image not displaying, try removing that and only having the bigPicture() method

Comment: google developer guide mentioned this.But i have tried removing this statement.but same result

Comment: Source: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#kotlin

Comment: yes now it is working in lollipop device..But not on upper devices like marshmallow :(

Comment: @SomerandomITboy can you reverse your downvote to an upvote plz since my solution is working.

Comment: @Aaron what should i do in if block?please suggest me

Comment: Without setting the SmallIcon the entire app crashes upon sending the notification

Comment: @UserAbdur just replace what was in your old if statement into what I have currently and it should work as expected

Comment: Android O and above crashes. Also not setting the large icon makes the notification to not display anything

Comment: @Aaron my previous code is not working.so shy should i write that code in if?

Comment: @UserAbdur You may have to come up with that on your own. I don't know what you want to happen for versions above Marshmello, but whatever you want done for versions above marshmellow set it in that first if statement. Also, upvote and accept the solution if the large picture solution worked :)

Comment: @UserAbdur dont forget to hit the check mark if the solution worked for you :)